# Update a string in an array mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I have a simple question lets say I have an array like numbers:[1,2,3]

And I want to search the whole collection and update every document that has in its numbers array the number 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Collection.find({'numbers': { $in:numbers}}).update(
        {$push:{numbers:2}}
    )
```